# The block in my game will not move when I use certain comands. I will press 'w' and it will not move up

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am using pygame in python3 and the character (the block) will not move when I use certain commands. I am confused on this problem, and need help, thanks. Also, I'm not worried about it I cannot x out of my tab. I am forced to force quit it.

```
    #Importing Modules
    from random import randint
    from pygame.locals import *
    import pygame
    ##################

    # Making User Controled Block
    class User_Block:
        def __init__(self):
          self.x_cor = 300
          self.y_cor = 300
          self.length = 20
          self.width = 20
          self.color = GREEN
          pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,[self.x_cor,self.y_cor,self.length,self.width],0)
    ##############################

    # Making Enemys
    class Enemy_Block:
        def __init__(self):
          self.x_cor = randint(100,500)
          self.y_cor = 100
          self.length = randint(10,100)
          self.width = randint(10,100)
          self.color = (255,0,255)
          pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,[self.x_cor,self.y_cor,self.length,self.width],5)
    ########################

    # Set Up Screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
    ##########################################

    # Varible Used "while" Loop
    done = False
    #############


    # Colors
    WHITE = (0,0,0)
    BLACK = (255,255,255)
    RED = (255,0,0)
    GREEN = (0,255,0)
    BLUE = (0,0,255)
    ########################

    # User Controled Block
    User_Block = User_Block()
    ########################

    # Enemys
    Enemy_List = []
    for i in range(10):
      Enemy_List.append(Enemy_Block())
    ######################

    # Most important code here
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              done == True

          #Moving Character
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
              User_Block.y_cor += 100
        Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        Clock.tick(60)
    ######################################

        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    ###################
```

The expected result is that my character will move up when I press "w". The actual result is that the block stays in its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here.

1. When you move the rect by changing its coordinates, you must redraw. `pygame` does not do it automatically. If you do not call the proper functions, the screen does not change.
2. You have `User_Block = User_Block()`. Don't use the same name of the class for its instance. At least use non capital letter: `user_block = User_Block()`. You are going to overwrite the reference to the class.

#### How to move images on the screen

In your code you use `pygame.draw.rect` instead of using a [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), so to remain consistent with this choice, you need to call again:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, ...)
```

after you update the coordinates. I suggest to put the command in a method of your classes, which you can call each iteration of the main loop when you need to redraw the position.
Remember to delete the rectangle at the previous position: pygame does not do it for you. You need to figure a way to do it.

Simplest but less efficient thing to do, is to fill the whole screen with the background color by calling `screen.fill(BLACK)` just before redrawing. Less efficient because you are in fact redrawing the whole screen and deleting also other images, which should be redrawn each iteration of the main loop.
This is the relevant code, put it just after the line where you update the coordinate:

```
screen.fill(BLACK) #note: black is (0, 0, 0) not (255, 255, 255).
user_block.draw()
for en in Enemy_List:
  en.draw()
```

Of course you need to define the `draw` method as I said above.

Finally, in the `pygame` coordinate system, the `y` increases going towards the bottom of the screen. Hence to go *up* you need to decrease the `y` value.

**Final Note:** as I said, drawing like this is inefficient. In this simple case is fine, but for complex games where a lot of things moves, will slow the game. We can do better, but I think explaining here goes too far the scope of the answer, you can research yourself how to do it, have a look at [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and its `blit` method to start.